# Render Partial View using jQuery .load() function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have project where when I insert something I want to refresh the partial view only or table only. When I click the button to insert it does insert but does not load the table, the table will just appear empty

View:

```
@model ClinicManagemet.Models.Assessment

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Update Assessment";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<h2>Assessment</h2>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn-disease').click(function () {
            var diseaseID = $('#DiseaseID').val();
            var assessmentID = $('#AssessmentID').val();
            var urll = '/DiseaseLists/_DiseaseList?id=' + assessmentID;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "Json",
                data: {
                    'diseaseID': diseaseID,
                    'assessmentID': assessmentID
                },
                url: '@Url.Action("CreateDisease", "DiseaseLists")',
                success: function (f) {
                    $('#tbl-disease').load(urll);
                    alert(f);
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AssessmentID)
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DiseaseID, "DiseaseID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("DiseaseID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DiseaseID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" id="btn-disease" value="Add" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2W col-md-10">
        <div id="tbl-disease">
            @{
                Html.RenderAction("_DiseaseList", "DiseaseLists", new { Model.AssessmentID });
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

partial view controller:

```
public ActionResult _DiseaseList(int? assessmentID)
    {
        var diseaseLists = db.DiseaseLists.Include(d => d.Assessment).Include(d => d.Disease).Where(d => d.AssessmentID == assessmentID);
        return PartialView(diseaseLists.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: try like this `$('#tbl-disease').load(
        '@Url.Action("_DiseaseList", "DiseaseLists",new {assessmentID = assessmentID})'
    );`

Comment: @Curiousdev it worked smoothly. thanks

Comment: @Mark no it'll not return `HTML` the ajax in example is referring different Action `@Url.Action("CreateDisease", "DiseaseLists")`

Comment: @kielou great :)

Comment: @Mark I don't know how to use html(). I don't really know how html() works.

Comment: Further references: [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) & [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Curiousdev said in the comment, I just changed some code in my jquery

```
$('#tbl-disease').load( '@Url.Action("_DiseaseList", "DiseaseLists",new {assessmentID = assessmentID})' );
```

Comment: Please Marked yor answer as accepted for future references

Comment: @Curiousdev I will, but I need to wait 2 days